# Creating "Type" object of a class by Type.getType

Tags: c#, object, .net-assembly

I am stuck here. In my vs solution we have 10 different projects. 
DAL contains 2 EF 6.0 objects, Say EG and EL.
I have an API project. In which I have a function as follows, I am trying to return properties of an EF class:

```
public IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetGetProperties(string className, string instanceType)
    {
        Type thisType;

        if (instanceType.Contains("G"))
        {
            thisType = Type.GetType("E.DAL.EG." + className);
        }
        else 
        {
            thisType = Type.GetType("E.DAL.EL." + className);
        }            
        return thisType.GetType().GetProperties();
    }
```

But every time "thisType" returns null. Is this because of the AssemblyInformation? if so what would be the correct code. I have Assembly's fully qualified name in string.
Thanks-- Anirban

Comment: I believe the return should be return thisType.GetProperties();

Comment: Thats a typo mistake here, thanks , I rectified it. But still the problem remains.

Comment: I had a typo too, check the comment now

Comment: thisType is itself a null value. thisType is returning correctly if that is in the same assembly.

Comment: I just remembered that you can get the assembly first somehow, and from it you do GetType, I don't remember how, but my internet connection doesn't allow me now to search.. Try to find it. Assembly something with the path to the assembly..

Comment: Check the last line in the answer, that's what I meant I think

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the last line. You are calling `.GetType()` on type `Type` (variable `thisType`) and that would return `RuntimeType` and not your type. The last line should be

```
return thisType.GetProperties();
```

and if your namespaces are correct, so you do have those namespaces (`E.DAL.EL` and `E.DAL.EG`) in the project, it will work.

If it doesn't check the namespaces and verify that those types are in the same assembly as your code! If they are in an external one you need to specify it for the `GetType` method.

Assuming those are in assembly named `SharedAssembly` then you need to load them this way

```
thisType = Type.GetType("E.DAL.EG." + className+ ", SharedAssembly");
```

Comment: Thanks Let me check